# Shiny Server app Running on Ubuntu 18.04 VM (VirtualBox) having issues with OpenStreetMaps (Java error)

Tags: java, ubuntu, virtual-machine, shiny-server, rjava

I am new to Shiny Server and not well versed in Linux so bear with me.

I'm running Shiny Server on Ubuntu 18.04, which is a virtual machine (VirtualBox). I am employing the OpenStreetMaps package in my app, which uses the rJava package. I had some trouble getting the rJava and OpenStreetMaps packages installed but finally managed after manually installing Java Runtime Environment and Java Development Kit with the terminal commands below:

```
* sudo apt update
* sudo apt install default-jre
* sudo apt install default-jdk
* sudo R CMD javareconf
* sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('rJava', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
* sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('OpenStreetMap', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

**All packages are in a global library /usr/local/lib/R/site-library.**

**When running the app through Shiny Server the error I get is:**

ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.

**When running the app through RStudio server I get the following error:**

Error in .jcall("java/lang/Class", "Ljava/lang/Class;", "forName", cl,  : 
  RcallMethod: cannot determine object class

Error in .jfindClass(as.character(class)) : 
  Java Exception .jfindClass(as.character(class))new("jobjRef", jobj = , jclass = "java/lang/Throwable")

Warning: Error in .tryJava: Java classes could not be loaded. Most likely because Java is not set up with your R installation.

Here are some trouble shooting tips:

1. Install Java (for mac consider installing java 1.6 from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US )
2. Run 
   R CMD javareconf
   in the terminal. If you are using Mac OS X >= 10.7 you may want to try
   R CMD javareconf JAVA_CPPFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
   instead.

   188: stop

   187: .tryJava

   186: openmap

   185:  [/home/amsp/Documents/MobileLab/app.R#326]

   183: .func

   180: contextFunc

   179: env$runWith

   172: ctx$run

   171: self$.updateValue

   169: map.latlon

   167: renderPlot [/home/amsp/Documents/MobileLab/app.R#347]

   165: func

   125: drawPlot

   111: reactive:plotObj

   95: drawReactive

   82: origRenderFunc

   81: output$plot_map1

   1: runApp

**I've tried to run Run R CMD javareconf and it doesn't solve this issue.**

**Checking Java yields:**

> java -version

openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

> javac -version

javac 11.0.6

**I'm wondering if maybe it is a permissions problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the whole thing seems like a versioning issue. OpenStreetMap doesn't seem to like Java 11, but most things are generally compatible with 8.

Reboot the VM to get a clean start and don't try to access either shiny or Rstudio before executing. Remove Java 11 and install java 8

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-11*

sudo apt-get install openjdk-8*

sudo R CMD javareconf

sudo service rstudio-server restart

sudo service shiny-server restart
```

Then accessed Shiny and it worked.